# ASP.NET VS2015 'iisexpress.exe has exited with code 42'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-express

I am no longer able to debug my ASP.NET MVC project. It worked fine until a few hours ago. I don't know what changes could've triggered the problem; I haven't changed "important" stuff. Heres the debug output:

```
.....
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/4/ROOT-1-131611094995769862): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The program '[10224] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[10224] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 42 (0x2a).
```

I've already tried to change the port, rebooted my computer a few times, tried running VS in admin-mode and deleted the .vs folder - No success. I don't receive any error messages.

So what could cause the problem and how do I fix that? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "I haven't changed "important" stuff". Define important. Seems likely you changed _something_.

Comment: Not changing important stuff only means, that I've just changed a html file.

Comment: It would still be helpful to know exactly what you changed. A change of some kind is the most likely source of the issue, tbh. Also, at what point in the process exactly do you get this error? Is the application not throwing some sort of exception when this happens?

Comment: That's the strange thing. The project builds without an exception (not even a warning). If I hit the "play" button, the project starts to go into debug mode. As soon as the first request is made to the project (eg localhost:1234), iisexpress.exe crashes.

Comment: builds don't produce exceptions (although they can produce build errors e.g. related to syntax issues). Exceptions are produced at runtime. If the process is exiting immediately it's possible an exception is occurring, although unlikely if the debugger isn't halting somewhere in the code.

Comment: Anyway, just to rule things out, revert any changes you've made to the code / config / project files since it worked properly, then go from there. If that doesn't fix it, copy your code files somewhere else, delete the solution completely and re-create it by adding your files back in manually. Ugly and tedious, but it'll rule out any corruption of the project files.

Comment: Alright, will try that out! Thanks @ADyson

Comment: So first I used the "repair" option for VS - no success. I also created and empty ASP.NET test-project. It worked. It worked like a charm. So it is definitely a problem in the project itself. Unfortunately I don't receive any debug / error messages (except the one I posted here). Also no breakpoint hitted :/

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this is so stupid but I still managed to solve this issue. Thank god we're using a version control system. So I could just re-download the project. Everything seems to work so far. Let's hope that the bug doesn't appear again.